# How to deallocate Linux RAMdisk

Tags: linux, memory, ramdisk

I am having trouble to deallocate RAMdisk in Linux.

I think that `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/ram0` used to work in the past.

But now:

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/ram0

md5sum /dev/ram0
c71df700969640324b201ae5f7a96c41  /dev/ram0

blockdev -v --flushbufs /dev/ram0
flush buffers succeeded.

md5sum /dev/ram0
c71df700969640324b201ae5f7a96c41  /dev/ram0
```

It did not wipe the RAMdisk. I tested in recent Linux 4.14 and 5.4.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://man.cx/freeramdisk(8)

Comment: you say kernel 4.14 and 5.4.  Isn't this all *tmpfs* now?  And does *flushing buffer* of a block device have any relevance in this context?  A buffer is not the contents of tmpfs.

Comment: `ls -l /dev/ram0` please. Is it actually a block device? The reason I'm asking is because the answer here definitely still works for me on kernel 4.9.35-v7+ (Raspberry Pi)

Comment: Yes, `/dev/ram0` is a block device. I looked into it more and found that BLKFLSBUF ioctl support for ramdisk was removed in 4.10 [link](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-block/msg05934.html). There is also something about implementing discard [link](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-block/msg05986.html) but `blkdiscard /dev/ram0` does not work for me in 5.4.61

Comment: How and where does the shown code de-allocate and free the ram disk?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there does not seem to be any other way to deallocate Linux ramdisk except using ramdisk as a module and removing the ramdisk module.